# Placeholder Profile Photos or Initials

Tags: design-patterns, profile, photos

Currently, I am working on how to increase engagement with profiles that have not set up a profile image. We currently have a person as a placeholder image (the common genderless placeholder photo), but we are looking into if it makes sense to use the member's Initials.

I am looking to see what members tend to like more/ what is most commonly used in the UX world? Have you seen any research that you have seen that supports one use over the other?

Comment: I'm not aware of any research, but I think it's probably the case that this would need to be handled with your particular users in context to your particular product. Maybe you could conduct your own research with some A/B or Multivariate testing to understand which your users prefer the most.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Research I don't know. There are articles like [**Design better avatars**](https://uxdesign.cc/design-avatars-that-make-sense-and-be-more-inclusive-in-the-process-d4dd6a486ea6), or [**6 ideas for creating better avatars**](https://uxplanet.org/6-ideas-for-creating-better-avatars-placeholders-a01cac5d7c6) (and there's more if you do a Google search) but I'd take these with a pinch of salt, because both articles simply suggest options but they don't support any of the choices, nor they offer any research to support them.

Personally, I think you should use avatars based on your target audience and brand voice. For example, if your project is formal and structured, using initials could be a good option, and same goes for the *"default"* user icon. But if your project is more hip, fun or for younger audiences, maybe you could go with mascots, toons, avatars or maybe even initial using a custom typography set. Once you find something you believe will work, just test it, as everything UX.

Comment: This was so helpful! I dug into the articles you linked and loved the tip of remembering to keep the target audience in mind. Thank you so much!